# D3 v3 with d3-force module on canvas

Tags: d3.js, canvas, force-layout, d3-force-directed

So am bit of a newbie to D3 and am facing a tricky problem:

I have an old D3 V3 implementation (with canvas) in which the tick function looks like this.

```
function onTick ()  {
     if (simulation.alpha() < 0.7) {
      simulation.alpha(0.7);
    }
}
```

I have added the new d3-force module so I can use the new forces…. In essence I want to use d3 v3 with the new d3-force modules

How would I change the tick in this case to do something like:

```
node
    .attr('cx', function(node) {
      return node.x
    })
    .attr('cy', function(node) {
      return node.y
    })

  link
    .attr('x1', function(link) {
      return link.source.x
    })
    .attr('y1', function(link) {
      return link.source.y
    })
    .attr('x2', function(link) {
      return link.target.x
    })
    .attr('y2', function(link) {
      return link.target.y
    })
```

Basically I would want the network to cool down/stop moving after its achieved balance (if that makes sense)